# Mac Audio output remove high pitch / high frequency sounds

Tags: mac, audio

I suffer from tinnitus and sometimes, in videos or video calls, there is a random high pitch noise which is really irritating for me. Also, in video calls some people talk really softly and some are really loud.

Is here an app which can act as a high pass filter for high pitch and frequency sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I recommend [Rouge Amoebas Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/).

What you are looking for is actually a low pass filter. Low frequencies should pass it, high frequencies should be attenuated.

Audio Hijack is a high-quality macOS audio tool, which offers not only audio manipulation via an equalizer, but also a dedicated low pass filter.

[image: Audio Hijack with Low Pass Filter]

Start Audio Hijack, add a *New Session* and select the preset *Sweeten*. This is a pre-build audio enhancement workflow for all sounds that are played by your selected output device. Then select the category *Build-in effects* and drag the *Low Pass Filter* block into the audio processing chain. It should look like the screenshot i attached. You can easily customize the cutoff frequency with a slider.

As soon as you press the start button on the bottom left, the audio effects will be applied.

In case a plain old equalizer is sufficient for you, you can try the free [eqMac App](https://eqmac.app/).

Comment: I'm a big fan of Rogue Amoeba - maybe in this case, [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) might be sufficient. It can access all the same plugins, built-in or 3rd party AUs & runs constantly in the menu bar, rather than having to be switched in & out as needed. It's about half the price too.

Comment: Great tip! I personally use Audio Hijack for recording purposes. But in this case, where it's only about direct output manipulation, SoundSource is the cheaper and equally sufficient option.

Comment: Yup - I tend to use Hijack on the 'pro' macs where I need it for occasional routing or recording but don't always need Loopback. For all the 'consumer' macs, or where I need just one dedicated audio path, like on my HTPC machine, SoundSource is simpler.

Comment: SoundSource worked great. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: can we use this along with spotify?

Comment: @alper Yes, it can modify all sound output :)

Comment: @iOSapps.de The app requires admin password it is safe to provide it?

Comment: @alper to modify audio output on a system-wide level, MacOS requires the admin password to install. So yes it is fine :)